# how to use images at the border of div tag all around to give custom border look?

Tags: html, css

i have set the following css to ger border image of the div container but the problem is that my right image is not coming right on the border but it leaves spaces from the right border side of the div container when it stretches out.

```
<div id="container">
<div id="left-image"></div>
<div id="main-containts">
    <div id="data-containts">
    data
    </div>
</div>
<div id="right-image"></div>



   <div id="bottom">

       <div id="bottom-left"></div>
       <div id="bottom-center"></div>
       <div id="bottom-right"></div>

   </div>


</div>



div#container{
    position:relative;
    margin-left:120px;
    margin-right:120px;
    float:top;
    padding-top:0;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
}
div#left-image{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:28px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background:url(border-left.png) repeat-y;   
    }

   div#right-image{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    float:right;
    width:30px;
    height:100%;
    margin-right:0;
    background:url(border-right.png) repeat-y;
    }   
    div#bottom{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:36px;
    z-index:100;
   }
    div#bottom-left{
width:51px;
height:36px;
background:url(corner-left.png) no-repeat;
float:left;
}   
div#bottom-center{

height:36px;
background:url(bottom-image.png) repeat-x;
margin-right:49px;
/*clear:both:*/
}       
    div#bottom-right{
width:49px;
height:36px;
background:url(corner-right.png) no-repeat;
float:right;
margin-top:-36px;

}
```

Comment: post your divs structure so that we can understand where the  problem is exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting the modern browsers only which supports css3. It could be easily accomplished by the css3 **border-image** property. Its worth to have a look at the property incase if you are not aware.

http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

Incase if you want your above code to work.Paste your div structure.

Comment: No but i have issue with cross browser compatibility. I want to use in almost all browser without any issue that's why started using images in border.